# How to configure the maven plugins to run spock and junit5 tests

Tags: maven, spock, junit5

I want to run run spock and junit5 tests in the same project. So I have made an example project with nothing under src/main but two tests under src/test/java/a/package/. One of the test is a junit5 and the other one is a spock test.

But after issuing `mvn test verify` only the JUnit test is executed but the spock test is not. They run nicely together in Intellij via "run all tests" so there is clearly some configuration issue I can not find.

Here is my maven pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>maven.spock.junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <poi.version>3.17</poi.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- test dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- spock testing framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-groovy-2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- hamcrest matcher -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass></mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- mvn test - exclude integration tests -->
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Xms2g -Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=500m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US</argLine>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>%regex[.*Fixme.*]</exclude>
                        <exclude>%regex[.*(Regression|Integration)Test.*]</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- mvn verify - execute integration tests only -->
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Xms2g -Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=500m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US -Duser.timezone=UTC</argLine>
                    <includes>
                        <include>%regex[.*(Regression|Integration)Test.*]</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>
                            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                            </includes>
                        </source>
                        <source>
                            <directory>src/test/groovy</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                            </includes>
                        </source>
                    </sources>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>skip-unit-tests</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>skipUnitTests</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                            <argLine>-Duser.timezone=UTC</argLine>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

If I use the following surefire configuration it executes the spock test but not the junit one.

```
        <plugin>
            <!-- mvn test - exclude integration tests -->
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <useFile>false</useFile>
                <argLine>-Xms2g -Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=500m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US</argLine>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Did you try to simulate the setup that is proposed by Spock here? https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: yes I did with slightly different versions but with the same versions as on github it does not change anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that maven gets confused with the dependencies so the junit dependencies need to go from the /project/dependencies into the surefire and failsafe plugin like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>maven.spock.junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>

        <groovy.version>2.5.2</groovy.version>
        <junit-platform.version>1.2.0</junit-platform.version>
        <jupiter.version>5.2.0</jupiter.version>
        <spock.version>1.2-groovy-2.5</spock.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type> <!-- required JUST since Groovy 2.5.0 -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>verify</defaultGoal>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testSources>
                        <testSource>
                            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                            </includes>
                        </testSource>
                        <testSource>
                            <directory>src/test/groovy</directory>
                            <directory>src/test</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                            </includes>
                        </testSource>
                    </testSources>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                            <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
                            <goal>compileTests</goal>
                            <goal>removeTestStubs</goal>
                            <goal>removeStubs</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>${jupiter.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>${jupiter.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <configuration>
                    <detail>true</detail>
                    <argLine>-Xms2g -Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=500m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US</argLine>
                    <includes>
                        <include>%regex[.*]</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>%regex[.*Fixme.*]</exclude>
                        <exclude>%regex[.*(Regression|Integration)Test.*]</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>${jupiter.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>${jupiter.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Xms2g -Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=500m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US -Duser.timezone=UTC</argLine>
                    <includes>
                        <include>%regex[.*(Regression|Integration)Test.*]</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

All the credit belong to SanderSmee - Thanks!! I was just so lucky that I have found your repo! https://github.com/SanderSmee/spock-jupiter/blob/master/pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

You have to help Surefire to pick the right provider, here the `surefire-junit-platform` provider:

```xml
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-junit-platform</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```

For details see https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/providers.html

Comment: hmmm I thought its not needed anymore. however still none of the tests get executed

Comment: Only dependency to junit-jupiter-engine is needed nothing else see https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html no provider....

Comment: Then Spock is not run. You also need the Spock engine at runtime --- and their transitive dependencies may confuse Surefire. This sample uses JUnit 3/4, Jupiter and JQwik: https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/master/surefire-its/src/test/resources/junit-platform-multiple-engines/pom.xml -- Spock should be _addable_ in a similar fashion.

Comment: yes the junit is running but the spock is not ... this is really a pain :-) I have added the dependencies like in the examples but this seems to be not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Spock 2.0 uses Junit 5, rather than JUnit 4. So, now, it just works without any special effort to get the dependencies correct.

Comment: On my side Spock tests run fine with `maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M4`, starting with `3.0.0-M5` the tests are not run.